# Searching in vectors of pairs

Tags: c++, vector

I have a 2d vector of pairs and I would like get in which row is a given pair.

I tried to iterate through all the elements but I didn't succeed.

Here is the adjacency matrix of an undirected, weighted graph:

```
vector<pair<int,int >> adj[20];
    for (int i = 1; i <= nodes; i++){
        f >> x >> y >> weight;

        adj[x].push_back(make_pair(weight, y));
        adj[y].push_back(make_pair(weight, x));
    }
```

And it looks like something like this:

(4,2),(5,3)

(4,1),(6,3)

(5,1),(6,2)

I am trying to find in which row is the pair (6,2)

```
typedef pair<int, int>p;
p pair= make_pair(6, 2);
cout << which_row(adj, pair);
```

Here is what I tried first:

```
int which_row(vector<p>adj[20], p pair) {
    vector <pair<int, int>> ::iterator it;

    for (int i = 0; i < adj->size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < adj[i].size(); i++) 
            if (pair.first == adj[i][j].first && pair.second == adj[i][j].second)
                return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

but it does not step in the for loop.

Second:

```
int which_row(vector<p>adj[20], p pair) {
    vector <pair<int, int>> ::iterator it;

    for (int i = 0; i <= adj->size(); i++) {
        for (it = adj[i].begin(); it != adj[i].end(); it++)
            if (pair.first == it->first && pair.second == it->second)
                return i;
    }

}
```

But it does not step in the second for loop.

What can I do?

Comment: what do you see when you debug? what are the values in the outer loop? if you can't use a debugger add debug printouts.

Comment: 1st version, inner loop, you probably mean to increment j

Comment: What do you think the value of `adj->size()` is?

Comment: the debugger says that the adj is empty(?) the first method always returns -1 and the second 0

Comment: yes, it should have been j++, thank you. still doesn't step into it:(

Comment: Since we can infer your `x` and `y` inputs from the pairs you gave us, you never push anything into `adj[0]`. `adj->size()` is the same as `adj[0].size()`. You never pushed anything into this so it will be `0`. It seems you want to go over every row? Each row contains a vector? Each vector contains some pairs? Make `adj` a `vector<vector<pair<int, int>>>` so you can access `adj.size()`. That's likely what you want. Or iterate from `i = 0; i < 20; i++` to go over each row.

Comment: the pairs which I gave are the made pairs by the initial loop, it is how it looks like now. yes, each row it a vector of pairs and the adj itself is a vector as I tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we can infer your `x` and `y` inputs from the pairs you gave us, you never push anything into `adj[0]`. `adj->size()` is the same as `adj[0].size()`. You never pushed anything into this so it will be `0`. It seems you want to go over every row? Each row contains a vector? Each vector contains some pairs? Make `adj` a `vector<vector<pair<int, int>>>` so you can access `adj.size()`. That's likely what you want. Or iterate from `i = 0; i < 20; i++` to go over each row.

Change your iteration to:

```
int which_row(vector<p>adj[20], p pair) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { // <-- changed to < 20 (not <= 20)
        for (auto it = adj[i].begin(); it != adj[i].end(); it++)
            if (pair == *it) // <-- pairs compare as you'd expect, no need to compare each element
                return i;
    }

    return -1; // need to return something if not found
}
```

Or we can take advantage of `std::find` in the `<algorithm>` library:

```
#include <algorithm>

int which_row(vector<p>adj[20], p pair) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { // <-- changed to < 20 (not <= 20)
        if (std::find(adj[i].begin(), adj[i].end(), pair) != adj[i].end())
            return i;
    }

    return -1; // need to return something if not found
}
```

If you change your `adj` initialization to `std::vector<std::vector<p>> adj(20);` you can change your `which_row` to:

```
// in main or whatever:
// makes a vector of 20 default-initialized (empty) vector<p>
std::vector<std::vector<p>> adj(20);

// elsewhere:
int which_row(vector<vector<p>> adj, p pair) {
    for (auto i = 0; i < adj.size(); i++) { // <-- adj is a vector now
        if (std::find(adj[i].begin(), adj[i].end(), pair) != adj[i].end())
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1; // need to return something if not found
}
```

Comment: thank you! can you explain the second method too, please? where you use ```vector<vector<pair<int, int>>>``` ? I think that's what will suit me because I don't know how many pairs will be in the input file